# Inserting value to all rows in one column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using VB.net 2013 and SQL Server 2012. I have a table `tblEmployeeInfo` with two columns, `EmployeeName` and `Date`:

```
EmployeeName   Date
--------------------
Jay            Null
Mike           Null
Paul           Null
```

When I input a date value in `Textbox1` like `3/20/2017`, it would insert that value into all rows into column `Date`.

```
EmployeeName   Date
-------------------------
Jay            3/20/2017
Mike           3/20/2017
Paul           3/20/2017
```

Please anyone help me out. Still no idea how to code using VB.net. My idea just to insert only using `WHERE` clause. But how to insert at once? Thank you guys.

Comment: Are there any existing rows which have a non-`null` `Date` value? Should they be over-written or left alone?

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach

```
DECLARE @NewDate DATETIME=GETDATE();
UPDATE tblEmployeeInfo SET [Date]=@NewDate;
```

Will set **all rows to the same value**. Is it really this you are trying to achieve?

If you want to hit only rows, where this value is `NULL` you can add

```
UPDATE tblEmployeeInfo SET [Date]=@NewDate WHERE [Date] IS NULL;
```

You - quite probably - have there some kind of grouping field where you want to set the new value selectively...? In this case just add an appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an update statement:

```
update tblEmployeeInfo set Date = @myDate
```

And add the @myDate as a parameter when calling the query.

Comment: Thank you Shnugo for your great idea and also to you Carra.